# font awesome use in kartik activeform - yii2

Tags: font-awesome, yii2

I have using kartik active form in my Yii2 development so i want to add icons into the form field. I was followed this [LINK](https://github.com/rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome) and tried below coding

//registered font awesome

```
rmrevin\yii\fontawesome\AssetBundle::register($this);

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); 

  <?= $form->field($model, 'Bags_count',[
        'feedbackIcon' => [
         'default' => 'sort-numeric-desc',
         'success' => 'ok',
         'error' => 'exclamation-sign',
        ]
   ])->textInput()->hint('&nbsp;&nbsp; Example: 4'); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I have found this unwanted coding by using chrome inspect element feature. hope this will helpful for the answer.

[image: inspect element]

[image: form field]

Comment: Default icons for karik-v form are glyphicon.  [See here](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform/blob/master/ActiveFormAsset.php) and simply you can try by changing [this line in widget](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform/blob/master/ActiveField.php#L1053)

Comment: thanks ! it's work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the widget function to use `font-awesome-class`

[Kartik-v Active Form Widget](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform/blob/master/ActiveField.php#L1053)

```
protected function renderFeedbackIcon()
{
    if (!$this->_hasFeedback) {
        return '';
    }
    $config = $this->feedbackIcon;
    $type = ArrayHelper::getValue($config, 'type', 'icon');
    $prefix = ArrayHelper::getValue($config, 'prefix', 'fa fa-');
    $id = Html::getInputId($this->model, $this->attribute);
    return $this->getFeedbackIcon($config, 'default', $type, $prefix, $id) .
    $this->getFeedbackIcon($config, 'success', $type, $prefix, $id) .
    $this->getFeedbackIcon($config, 'error', $type, $prefix, $id);
}
```